# Url not work in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I just uploaded my demo project in subfolder on godaddy. When I open a website url ***example.com/demo*** Home page works fine but when I open inner pages my url looks like ***example.com/demo/index.php?/home/overview***.(with question marks)

I just want to rewrite my url and i am trying to remove index.php after removing my url look like ***example.com/demo/home/overview*** but it didn't work.

Need a better solution.

My .htaccess file and config file are uploaded here:

[Godaddy - Codeigniter - No input file specified on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523834/godaddy-codeigniter-no-input-file-specified-on-server/39524436#39524436)

Answer (score 1):

edit in htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /demo/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

*configure base url in **config.php** file also.*

Answer (score 0):

**check config.php file**

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/projectname";
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

**sometime it causes troubles due to htaccess file**

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|system|css|js|style|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

*in the ReWriteCond part add your folder/file names manually. make sure you keep the names seperated by ' | '*
the above change worked for me